# Turtle python library not importing

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am pretty new with python and programming. I started using the turtle library but when I installed the library with pip, this error showed:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-sr9ppuq0/turtle/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-sr9ppuq0/turtle/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-sr9ppuq0/turtle/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-sr9ppuq0/turtle/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-sr9ppuq0/turtle/setup.py", line 40
        except ValueError, ve:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

When I imported the python library, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
    import tkinter as TK
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

please help. And I am also on a linux system.

Comment: That `turtle` module you're trying to install via `pip` is NOT the turtle graphics module you're probably looking for.  You don't want it, and it's not going to run on any modern system anyway (last updated in 2009).  The *real* `turtle` is part of Tkinter, no separate installation required.  Since Tkinter apparently didn't come pre-installed on your system, you will need to use your system's package manager to get it - it will be called something like "python-tk", I think.

Comment: After installing python-tk through apt, it still shows the same error.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `python -m pip install PythonTurtle`, i think that's the newest installation name

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: After installing the python library using that command, `import turtle;` still shows the same error

Comment: This isn't a helpful answer. The OP is trying to use the built-in turtle module and this is likely to be confusing for beginners as it is actually suggesting installing a third party package with a similar name from PyPI